# NoMethodError in StaticPages#Home (undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to extend the Rails Tutorial Sample App to include replies.

I created a Recipient model that contains a `user_id` to designate the person to whom the reply is addressed and a `micropost_id`.

I added the following to my User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :replies, foreign_key: "user_id", class_name: "Recipient", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :received_replies, through: :replies, source: :micropost
  ...
  def feed
    Micropost.from_followed_by_and_replying_to(self)
  end
  ...
end
```

And this to my Micropost model:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
  has_many :recipients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :replied_users, through: :recipients, :source => "user"
  ...
  def self.from_followed_by_and_replying_to(user)
    followed_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                    WHERE followed_id = :user_id"
    replier_ids  = "SELECT micropost_id FROM recipients
                    WHERE user_id = :user_id"
    where("user_id in (#{followed_ids}) 
           OR id in (#{replier_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", 
           user_id: user.id)
  end
  ...
end
```

The StaticPages#home action loads the feed:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if signed_in?
      @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Then when signed in and visiting the home page, I get `NoMethodError in StaticPages#Home` for the shared `feed_item` partial (app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb) at this line:

```
 <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
```

It's `undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass` (presumably from `user.email` which the `gravatar_for` helper method uses.

When I call `Micropost.from_followed_by_and_replying_to([some user])` in the rails console, it has no trouble returning both the microposts from followed users as well as replies, so I don't think my db querying is incorrect here. Any help is appreciated, I'm really stumped.

**edit: (removed some HTML from these)**

app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
...
  <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
  <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
  <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
  <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
...
<% else %>
...
<% end %>
```

app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

app/views/shared/_feed_items.html.erb:

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
<%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
...
</li>
```

Comment: Can you also post your `home.html.erb`?

Comment: Do you have a belongs_to :user in your Micropost class?

Answer (score 0):

If `gravatar_for` calls `email` on the user you pass to it, then the error message is telling you that `feed_item.user` is `nil`.

Try putting `<% raise feed_item.user %>` the line before the `link_to`, and see if it is indeed `nil`. Also, a stack trace of the error is one of the most useful things you can put in a SO question.